# How to push data from API in row on framework material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I need to push data from API
the variable on API is referenced from the field.
I don't know how to write array in rows please help.
#############################################################

```
const BasicFiltering() => {

    const [ListSpare , setListSpare] = useState([]);
    const SelectProjects = () => {
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/something`)
          .then((response)=>{
            setListSpare(response.data)
            console.log(val)
            
            
          })
          .catch(()=>{
                console.log("err")
                
                  
                  
          });
  }
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Basic Filtering Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'SN', field: 'Serial' },
        { title: 'PID', field: 'PID' },
        { title: 'HostName', field: 'Host Name' },
        { title: 'Product',field: 'Product'}
      ]}
      data={[ListSpare]}   
      options={{
        filtering: true
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if ListSpare is already array, no need to pass it inside array in data

```
data={ListSpare}
```

As by looking at your comment, it seems data is not in array so you can use spread operator here

```
data={[...ListSpare]}
```

Comment: { SN: 'FJSSD223', Product: 'Tenv, HostName: "H24-22D", PID:"GEE" }, { SN: 'FJSSD334', Product: 'Tenv, HostName: "H24-21D", PID:"GEE" },  { SN: 'FJSMM221', Product: 'Tenv, HostName: "H24-11D", PID:"GEE" } it getting from response.data